# how to export class and use it in enzyme test

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, redux-saga

I should to test component without redux side. i imported it like

```
import { CustomersPage, IProps } from '../Page';
```

but it return  Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to expo
rt your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports this error

and export it in like `export class CustomersPage extends React.Component<IProps> {}`
and also exported default for redux

```
export default withRouter<any>(
    connect<IStateProps, IDispatchProps>(
        (appState: IMainReduxState) => ({

        }),
        {
           },
    )(CustomersPage),
);
```

Comment: can you show us the complete code of CustomersPage component?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with upgrade jest/enzyme version